# Component (note) dragging on a piano staff

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I've got a Picturebox, which the user can drag up or down. The PictureBox represents a note on a piano staff. When the note is moved up or down, the note's position is to change relative to the staff lines. Hence, the positions can ONLY be moved to fixed positions (Y-values). Thus, when the user moves a note vertically, it is not supposed to be placed anywhere, but only in specified positions (dictated by the if statements).

The issue is that the user is able to move the PictureBox (music note) component down, but when the object is dragged up, nothing happens. The class inherits from PictureBox.

I would just like to emphasise that the PictureBox works when dragged downwards, but does not move when dragged upwards. The dragging is done in intervals, i.e. the PictureBox can only be placed in certain places (hence the need for specific co-ordinates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails because the if statement when moving up includes the current position. E.g when this.Top is 138 and the mouse moved up you'll hit this if statement: `else if (this.Top < 148 && this.Top >= 138)` which will set the top to 138 which it already was. You should move the `=` sign to the other side like this: `if (this.Top <= 148 && this.Top > 138)`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using lots of if statements create a list of allowed Y coordinates, then whenever the note moves, iterate through the list until you find the closest allowed coordinate and move there. Something like below:

```
List<int> AllowedYs;
// TODO: Add coordinates to your list

var FinalY = AllowedYs.OrderBy(y => Math.Abs(y - e.Y)).First();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isnt my problem.

Comment: What is then? I've given you an answer that will allow you to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: The MOVING of the note. As i said, the note works when moving down, but not up. So it's something to do with the PictureBox most likely. The if statements are just temporary for now

Comment: Apply my code every time e.Y changes, and you'll get what you want.

Comment: The error is probably in the logic of the if statements (probably need to reverse the order of them in the half where you're moving up or something), if you use my code it should be a lot easier to follow, if you still have issues i'll try and troubleshoot

Comment: I've tried implementing your code, but OrderBy is not accepted. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a LINQ extension method, add `using System.Linq` at the top of your code, and if you're not referencing it already, add a reference to `System.Core`. If you're not using .net 3.5 you'll have to re-write the code so it doesn't rely on that.

Comment: @Sean: That's fine, but if the if statements are only temporary consider my answer when you want to move away from them. :)